# What is the correct order of send and receive in MPI_Neighbor_alltoallw()?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am using [MPI_Neighbor_alltoallw()](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.1/man3/MPI_Neighbor_alltoallw.3.php) to send and receive data from neighboring processes. In my application, I have ghost cells, which should be updated by copying cell data from neighboring cells. Here is a schematic of this process:

[image: The blue cells, contain data and the purple cells are ghost cells, which should be updated with a copy of neighboring cell data.]
*The blue cells, contain data and the purple cells are ghost cells, which should be updated with a copy of neighboring cell data.*

According to what I learned from [MPI standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), I wrote the simplest example I could. I also wrote a parallel vtk writer to visualize the data later. In the following code I defined new MPI data types for sending and receiving sub-arrays:

```
#include <mpi.h>

//VTK Library
#include <vtkXMLPStructuredGridWriter.h>
#include <vtkXMLStructuredGridWriter.h>
#include <vtkStructuredGrid.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkFloatArray.h>
#include <vtkCellData.h>
#include <vtkProgrammableFilter.h>
#include <vtkInformation.h>
#include <vtkMPIController.h>

// To change the number of processes in each direction change nx, ny
const int nx{2};
const int ny{2};
const int Lx{100/nx};   // grid size without ghost cells
const int Ly{100/ny};
const int lx{Lx+4};     // grid size plus ghost cells
const int ly{Ly+4};

struct Args {
  vtkProgrammableFilter* pf;
  int local_extent[6];
};

// function to operate on the point attribute data
void execute (void* arg) {
  Args* args = reinterpret_cast<Args*>(arg);
  auto info = args->pf->GetOutputInformation(0);
  auto output_tmp = args->pf->GetOutput();  //WARNING this is a vtkDataObject*
  auto input_tmp  = args->pf->GetInput();   //WARNING this is a vtkDataObject*
  vtkStructuredGrid* output = dynamic_cast<vtkStructuredGrid*>(output_tmp);
  vtkStructuredGrid* input  = dynamic_cast<vtkStructuredGrid*>(input_tmp);
  output->ShallowCopy(input);
  output->SetExtent(args->local_extent);
}

void parallel_vtk_writer (double* cells, const char* name, int* coords, int* dim, vtkMPIController* contr) {
  int dims[2] = {lx+1, ly+1};
  int global_extent[6] = {0, dim[1]*lx, 0, dim[0]*ly, 0, 0};
  int local_extent[6] = {coords[1]*lx, coords[1]*lx + lx,
                        coords[0]*ly, coords[0]*ly + ly, 0, 0};

  int nranks = contr->GetNumberOfProcesses();
  int rank   = contr->GetLocalProcessId();

  auto points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
  points->Allocate((lx+1)*(ly+1));
  for (int j=0; j<ly+1; ++j)
    for (int i=0; i<lx+1; ++i)
      points->InsertPoint(i + j*(lx+1), i+coords[1]*lx, j+coords[0]*ly, 0);

  auto cell_value = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
  cell_value->SetNumberOfComponents(1);
  cell_value->SetNumberOfTuples(lx*ly);
  cell_value->SetName ("cell value");

  for (int j=0; j<ly; ++j)
    for (int i=0; i<lx; ++i)
      cell_value->SetValue(i + j*lx, cells[i + j*lx]);

  auto pf = vtkSmartPointer<vtkProgrammableFilter>::New();

  Args args;
  args.pf = pf;
  for(int i=0; i<6; ++i) args.local_extent[i] = local_extent[i];

  pf->SetExecuteMethod(execute, &args);

  auto structuredGrid = vtkSmartPointer<vtkStructuredGrid>::New();
  structuredGrid->SetExtent(global_extent);
  pf->SetInputData(structuredGrid);
  structuredGrid->SetPoints(points);
  structuredGrid->GetCellData()->AddArray(cell_value);

  auto parallel_writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPStructuredGridWriter>::New();
  parallel_writer->SetInputConnection(pf->GetOutputPort());
  parallel_writer->SetController(contr);
  parallel_writer->SetFileName(name);
  parallel_writer->SetNumberOfPieces(nranks);
  parallel_writer->SetStartPiece(rank);
  parallel_writer->SetEndPiece(rank);
  parallel_writer->SetDataModeToBinary();
  parallel_writer->Update();
  parallel_writer->Write();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);  

  //*** Create cartesian topology for grids ***//
  MPI_Comm comm_cart;
  int cartesian_rank;
  int dim[2] = {ny, nx};
  int coords[2];
  int periods[2] = {1, 1};
  MPI_Cart_create (MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dim, periods, 0, &comm_cart);
  MPI_Comm_rank (comm_cart, &cartesian_rank);
  MPI_Cart_coords (comm_cart, cartesian_rank, 2, coords);

  //******** Allocate memory and initialize cells ********//
  double* cells = new double[lx*ly];
  for (int j=0; j<ly; ++j)
    for (int i=0; i<lx; ++i)
      cells[i + j*lx] = 0;

  //********* Assign a value to cells *********//
  int cx = coords[1];
  int cy = coords[0];
  int l, m;
  // for loops starts with 2, because we don't initialize the ghost cells
  for (int j=2; j<ly-2; ++j)
    for (int i=2; i<lx-2; ++i) {
      l = i + cx*lx - 4*cx;
      m = j + cy*ly - 4*cy;
      if ((l-(nx*Lx+3)/2.)*(l-(nx*Lx+3)/2.) + (m-(ny*Ly+3)/2.)*(m-(ny*Ly+3)/2.) <= 400)
        cells[i + j*lx] = (i+j)*0.1;
      else
        cells[i + j*lx] = 0.1;
    }

  //********** Define new data types **********//
  const int dims {2};
  int arr_sizes[dims] = {ly, lx};
  int subar_sizes_x[dims] = {Ly, 2};
  int subar_sizes_y[dims] = {2, Lx};
  MPI_Datatype subar_right;
  MPI_Datatype subar_left;
  MPI_Datatype subar_top;
  MPI_Datatype subar_bottom;
  MPI_Datatype ghost_left;
  MPI_Datatype ghost_right;
  MPI_Datatype ghost_bottom;
  MPI_Datatype ghost_top;

  // send subarrays
  int subar_right_start[dims] = {2, Lx};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_x, subar_right_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &subar_right);
  MPI_Type_commit (&subar_right);

  int subar_left_start[dims] = {2, 2};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_x, subar_left_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &subar_left);
  MPI_Type_commit (&subar_left);

  int subar_top_start[dims] = {Ly, 2};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_y, subar_top_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &subar_top);
  MPI_Type_commit (&subar_top);

  int subar_bottom_start[dims] = {2, 2};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_y, subar_bottom_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &subar_bottom);
  MPI_Type_commit (&subar_bottom);

  // recv subarrays
  int ghost_left_start[dims] = {2, 0};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_x, ghost_left_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &ghost_left);
  MPI_Type_commit (&ghost_left);

  int ghost_right_start[dims] = {2, Lx+2};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_x, ghost_right_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &ghost_right);
  MPI_Type_commit (&ghost_right);

  int ghost_bottom_start[dims] = {0, 2};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_y, ghost_bottom_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &ghost_bottom);
  MPI_Type_commit (&ghost_bottom);

  int ghost_top_start[dims] = {Ly+2, 2};
  MPI_Type_create_subarray (dims, arr_sizes, subar_sizes_y, ghost_top_start, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &ghost_top);
  MPI_Type_commit (&ghost_top);

  //******** SENDING SUBARRAY ********//
  int sendcounts[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
  int recvcounts[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
  MPI_Aint sdispls[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
  MPI_Aint rdispls[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
  MPI_Datatype sendtypes[4] = {subar_bottom, subar_top, subar_left, subar_right};
  MPI_Datatype recvtypes[4] = {ghost_top, ghost_bottom, ghost_right, ghost_left};
  MPI_Neighbor_alltoallw (cells, sendcounts, sdispls, sendtypes, cells, recvcounts, rdispls, recvtypes, comm_cart);

  //******** Writing the cells using VTK ********//
  auto contr = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMPIController>::New();
  contr->Initialize(nullptr, nullptr, 1);
  parallel_vtk_writer (cells, "data/grid.pvts", coords, dim, contr);

  //******** Free data types ********//
  MPI_Type_free (&subar_right);
  MPI_Type_free (&subar_left);
  MPI_Type_free (&subar_top);
  MPI_Type_free (&subar_bottom);
  MPI_Type_free (&ghost_left);
  MPI_Type_free (&ghost_right);
  MPI_Type_free (&ghost_bottom);
  MPI_Type_free (&ghost_top);
  delete[] cells;

  MPI_Finalize ();
  return 0;
}
```

I am using the following CmakeList to make my executable:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(TEST)
add_executable(TEST test_stackoverflow.cpp)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(TEST ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
target_link_libraries(TEST ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
```

### Question

When I use a 2 by 2 process grid ([nx,ny] = [2,2]) the send and receive works properly. However, when I use 4 by 4 process grid, I see the wrong result (wrong send and receive). **What is the correct oreder of sendtypes and recvtypes in MPI_Neighbor_alltoallw()?**

Any suggestions to improve the code are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MPI 3.1 standard chapter 7.6 page 314

> For a Cartesian topology, created with MPI_CART_CREATE, the sequence of neighbors in the send and receive buffers at each process is defined by order of the dimensions, first the neighbor in the negative direction and then in the positive direction with displacement 1.

I empirically found in the case of a 2D cartesian communicator, the sequence is :

- top
- bottom
- left
- right

(I tested both Open MPI and MPICH, though I have some hard time understanding the logic here ...)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tested [top, bottom, left, right] order but still I do not have correct communication with neighbors. The thing that I do not understand is that why a specific order works for 2*2 process grid but not for [nx*ny : nx>2 & ny>2]?

Comment: After about one year I returned to this question again. For the code that I posted, the correct orders are:
`sendtypes[4] = {subar_bottom, subar_top, subar_left, subar_right};` and
`recvtypes[4] = {ghost_bottom, ghost_top, ghost_left, ghost_right};`.
I checked my code with **Intel MPI** and **Open MPI** and it works correctly.

Comment: @Ali See https://github.com/mpi-forum/mpi-issues/issues/153. There is a bug in the specification and/or all major MPI implementations :(